# If $T$ is one-to-one, then $T^*T$ is invertible and $T^+=(T^*T)^{-1}T^*$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional inner product spaces, and $T:V\to W$ is linear.
> Then if $T$ is one-to-one, then $T^*T$ is invertible and $T^+=(T^*T)^{-1}T^*$. If $T$ is onto, then $TT^*$ is invertible and $T^+=T^*(TT^*)^{-1}$.

I want to use Penrose conditions to show $T^+=(T^*T)^{-1}T^*$. But I have no idea how to prove

$$TU=T(T^*T)^{-1}T^*$$ is self-adjoint.

Do I need to prove $(T^*T)^{-1}$ is self-adjoint? Can someone help me, thanks a lot.

Comment: What does $T^+$ mean?

Comment: pseudo inverse of $T$

Comment: @StevenLu One approach is indeed to note that $TU$ is self-adjoint. Note that $T^*T$ is self adjoint and that $(A^*)^{-1} = (A^{-1})^*$. In general, note that $(AB)^* = B^*A^*$.

Comment: I got it, thanks!